# The right position of "too" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, too-also

1. > A would fail to explain X.
2. > B would fail to explain Y.
3. > B would fail to explain X.

Where to put "too" in the third sentence to mean that "next to A, B would fail to explain X" and not to mean "next to Y, B would fail to explain X"?

Comment: Why do you even think that adding "too" in any position to "B would fail to explain X" would make it mean "B would explain X." And what does "next to" mean in terms of explanations? Under what circumstances would these conclusions hold: you used "would"? Your question is unanswerable in its current form because it makes no sense.

Comment: @JeffMorrow edited.

Comment: OK I see the edit, and that makes the question quite a bit clearer, but I still am bemused by "next to," which usually means to positioning in physical, temporal, or social space. That does not seem to mean what you mean.

Comment: I'm finding these questions from this OP to be basically editing questions.  The sentences are all the same. Agree with JeffMorrow.

Answer (score 0):

"A would fail to explain X, and B would fail too," would mean "A and B would fail to explain X".

"A would fail to explain Y, and fail to explain X too," would mean "A would fail to explain X and Y".

Neither of these statements are conditional; neither means "If A fails to explain X, then B fails to explain it too."

Comment: I want separate sentences.

Comment: "A would fail to explain X. B would fail to explain it, too" would work for the first, but it would be unlikely to be used by native speakers. Usually you'd say something like "A would fail to explain X. B would also fail at it." Similarly, for the second, "A would fail to explain Y. A would also fail to explain X, too" would work, but the fact that they share the same subject and verb would mean that most native speakers would collapse them into a compound sentence to avoid repeating themselves, unless it's something that they just thought of while they were talking.

Answer (score 0):

In separate sentence it would be:

> 1- A would fail to explain X.
>   2- B would fail to explain Y.
>   3- B would fail to explain X, too.

You could add it at the end of sentence, and insert "," before that.